# The Lefschetz operator

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, sg.symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry

Let $\omega=\sum_{i=1}^n dx_i\wedge dy_i\in\bigwedge^2(\mathbb{R}^{2n})^*$ be a standard symplectic form. The following result is due to Lefschetz:

> For $k\leq n$, the Lefschetz operator
> $L^{n-k}:\bigwedge^k(\mathbb{R}^{2n})^*\to
>  \bigwedge^{2n-k}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})^*$ defined by  $$
>  L^{n-k}\alpha=\alpha\wedge\underbrace{\omega\wedge\ldots\wedge\omega}_{n-k}=\alpha\wedge\omega^{n-k}
> $$ is an isomorphism.

This follows from Proposition 1.2.30 [1]. The proof is slick and it uses representation theory.

> **Question:** What are other standard references for this result? I want to quote it properly and I would like to see a reference to a
> proof by brute force. A proof by brute force is not difficult but ugly
> and perhaps in some reference I can find an elegant presentation of
> such a proof.

This result seems so fundamental that it should be available in many textbooks, but I am not aware of any except [1].

[1] **D. Huybrechts,**  [*Complex geometry. An introduction.*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b137952). Universitext. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2005.

[(MathsciNet review)](https://mathscinet-ams-org.pitt.idm.oclc.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=JOUR&pg7=REFF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=Huybrechts&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=Books&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=4&mx-pid=2093043).

Comment: Another older reference for this result is  André Weil *Introductions à l'étude des variétés kählériennes*, Herman 1958. (The corollary on page 28 is the reuslt you mentioned.The proof  is the standard proof using representations of $sl_2$.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is an elementary proof in our 2003 book *Exterior Differential Systems and Euler-Lagrange Partial Differential Equations* (Bryant, et al, University of Chicago Press). It does not use any representation theory and is not 'brute force'; it only takes a couple of paragraphs using elementary facts about exterior algebra. See Proposition 1.1a, with the proof on page 13.

I learned that proof from Eugenio Calabi more than 30 years ago, and he told me that he had found it sometime back in the 50s.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Wow. That's the easiest shortest brute force proof I've ever seen. It can be found on arxiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0207039

Answer (score 19):

I find the proof mentioned by [**Robert Bryant**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/316527/121665) so beautiful that I cannot resist and I have to include it here. The following proof is from [1] Proposition 1.1a.

> **Definition.** Given $w\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $1\leq k\leq n$, we define the  *interior product* $$
>  \iota_w:\bigwedge\nolimits^k(\mathbb{R}^n)^*\to
>  \bigwedge\nolimits^{k-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)^* \quad \text{by} \quad
>  \iota_w(\xi)(v_1,\ldots,v_{k-1})=\xi(w,v_1,\ldots,v_{k-1}). $$

For the proof of the next lemma see Proposition 2.12 in [2].

> **Lemma.** If $\xi\in \bigwedge\nolimits^k(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$, $\eta\in \bigwedge\nolimits^\ell(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then
>   $$
>  \iota_v(\xi\wedge\eta)=\iota_v(\xi)\wedge\eta+(-1)^k\xi\wedge\iota_v(\eta). $$

This lemma and a simple induction imply that
$$
\iota_v(\omega^k)=k\omega^{k-1}\wedge\iota_v(\omega),
\quad
\text{for $v\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)
$$

Now we can prove the main result:

> **Theorem.** For $1\leq k\leq n$, the *Lefschetz operator* $$ L^k:\bigwedge\nolimits^{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})^*\to
>  \bigwedge\nolimits^{n+k}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})^*, \quad L^k(\xi)=\xi\wedge\omega^k
>  $$ is an isomorphism.

**Proof.**
Since the spaces $\bigwedge\nolimits^{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})^*$ and $\bigwedge\nolimits^{n+k}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})^*$ have equal dimensions, it suffices to show that $L^k$ is injective. We will use a backwards induction starting with $k=n$. If $k=n$, then $\omega^n=n!dVol$ and it is obvious that
$$
L^n:\bigwedge\nolimits^0(\mathbb{R}^{2n})^*=\mathbb{R}\to \bigwedge\nolimits^{2n}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})^*
$$
is an isomorphism and hence injective.

Suppose that the result is true for $k$. We need to prove it is true for $k-1$. Thus 
we need to prove that if
$L^{k-1}(\xi)=\xi\wedge\omega^{k-1}=0$ for some
$\xi\in\bigwedge\nolimits^{n-(k-1)}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})^*$, then $\xi=0$.

Clearly, $\xi\wedge\omega^k=0$. If $v\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, then the Lemma and (*) yield
$$
0=\iota_v(\xi\wedge\omega^k)=
\iota_v(\xi)\wedge\omega^k\pm \xi\wedge\iota_v(\omega^k)=
\iota_v(\xi)\wedge\omega^k\pm k\underbrace{\xi\wedge\omega^{k-1}}_{0}\wedge\iota_v(\omega)
$$
so $L^k(\iota_v(\xi) )=\iota_v(\xi)\wedge\omega^k=0$ and hence $\iota_v(\xi)=0$ by the injectivity of $L^k$ (induction hypothesis).
Since $\iota_v(\xi)=0$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, it follows that $\xi=0$. The proof is complete.
$\Box$

**[1] R. Bryant, P. Griffiths, D. Grossman,**  [*Exterior differential systems and Euler-Lagrange partial differential equations.*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0207039) Chicago Lectures in Mathematics. University of Chicago Press, Chicago, IL, 2003.

**[2] F. W. Warner,** *Foundations of differentiable manifolds and Lie groups.* Corrected reprint of the 1971 edition. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 94. Springer-Verlag, New York-Berlin, 1983.