# $\omega$ is a symplectic form then $L^k_{\omega}:\Omega^q(M)\to \Omega^{q+2k}(M)$ is injective for all $q\leq n-k$ and surjective for all $q\geq n-k$

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, differential-forms

Let $(M^{2n},\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold of dimension $2n$. Let $L^k_{\omega}:\Omega^q(M)\to \Omega^{q+2k}(M)$ be the map given by $L^k_{\omega}(\alpha)=\alpha\wedge\omega^k$. Then is it true that $L^k_{\omega}$ is injective for all $q\leq n-k$ and surjective for all $q\geq n-k$?

It seems that this is true, but I could not find a proof for it. Can anyone provide a proof for this, or atleast point out where can I get the proof for this.

Comment: This is not true. It fails quite generally. See papers by Li Sheng Tseng with Tsai and Yau and others.

Comment: @DanFox which paper? is it "Cohomology and Hodge Theory on symplectic manifolds"?

Comment: One standard keyword you should be looking at is "strong Lefschetz property".

Comment: @Uncool: The paper you mention is an overview, if I remember right. There is a series of numbered papers that have all the details.

Comment: @DanFox Yes its a series of paper

Comment: [Crossposted on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4362218/39599).

Comment: @Uncool: Start with the one numbered 1.

Comment: You might also want to look at "Hodge Structure on Symplectic Manifolds" by Dong Yan which includes a nice proof of Mathieu's theorem on the relationship between HL and the existence of (symplectic) harmonic forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The injectivity case is well-known and follows quite easily from the statement (usually attributed to Lefschetz) that $L^k_\omega:\Omega^{n-k}(M)\to \Omega^{n+k}(M)$ is a isomorphism for $0\le k\le n$.

This is a purely linear algebra statement and only relies on $\omega$ being nondegenerate, i.e., that $\omega^n$ be nonvanishing; $\omega$ does not need to be closed for this isomorphism to hold.

N.B.:  Just for clarity's sake, let me point out that I am assuming that the OP intends $\Omega^p(M)$ to mean the module of (smooth) $p$-forms on $M$, as is standard.   I'm not sure why people are bringing up comments about cohomology and hard Lefschetz, as the question (as I understand it) really has nothing to do with that.

For a discussion of the linear algebra result, see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316505/the-lefschetz-operator/316527#316527) and its answers.

Comment: I think both injectivity and surjectivity follow from the statement mentioned by you.

Comment: @Uncool:  Yes, that's correct.